# django appends django to class names in INSTALLED_APPS automatically

Tags: python, django

I have an app named `code_cloud` in `ccloud` project.

I have
`default_config = 'code_cloud.apps.CodeCloudConfig'`
in `code_cloud/__init__.py`
following is relevant section of `ccloud/settings.py`:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'code_cloud'
    ....
]
```

When I do `python manage.py makemigrations code_cloud`, I get

```
....
ImportError: No module named 'code_clouddjango'
```

why is django appending django to module before searching. I have django version 1.9.2

Comment: Do you have a comma (`,`) after `'code_cloud'` in your `INSTALLED_APPS`?

Comment: If you find some answer useful. Mark it as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have missed a comma between `'code_cloud'` and ̀`'django'` which results into strings concatenation.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'code_cloud'
    'django',
    ...
]
```

Should be:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'code_cloud',
    'django',
    ...
]
```